# Search result URL mapping

Tags: url, url-rewriting, mapping, search-engine

Can I map the search result url to a static URL?

If you search **stack**, most search engine result url will be /?q=**stack**, but i want to map the result url to be /**1**

If you search **overflow**, the result url will be /**2**
...

What is your ideas?

Comment: In general you should also explain why you want to do something to get the best answers.

Comment: I want to get a shorter url and with the params encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do this by treating the # in "/#" as a query string instead of a file.  This can be done through your web server.  You could store that Search_ID in the database with the associated results.

Comment: bruce, is this answer good for you?  if not could you explain why